# How can I indent selected lines in Visual mode by space granularity instead of TABs?

Tags: indentation, visual-mode, selection

How can I indent lines selected in Visual mode using space granularity instead of than TABs (i.e. `<` or `>`)?

Sometimes when coding Python, I need to indent lines to a level that is not a TAB boundary.

Selecting the lines by pressing `V` to enter Visual mode and then using `<` or `>` to indent them doesn't let me indent the lines to the anticipated level.

Any ideas?

**Update**:

Suppose after some edits, the dots ('`.`') are not aligned, which they must be in order to satisfy the Flake8 Python linter:

```
    # Flake8: All dots ('.') should be aligned over each other
    proj_object = self.session.query(Project) \
                            .filter(Project.id == parsed_proj.id) \
                            .one_or_none()
```

In particular, all dots must have the same indentation as the topmost dot, which is not on a TAB boundary. It's very cumbersome to manually ident each line individually using SPACEs... I'd like to indent all lines in Visual mode at once using SPACEs (not TABs):

```
    # Flake8: No complains
    proj_object = self.session.query(Project) \
                              .filter(Project.id == parsed_proj.id) \
                              .one_or_none()
```

**NB**: I have looked at `expandtab`, but that doesn't really suit my needs.

Comment: @Biggybi was right in his comment `expandtab` sounds like what you are looking for. Could you explain why that doesn't suit your needs? It would be nice that you edit your question with a snippet of code and what you actually want to do with it otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: expandtab + shiftwidth + softtabstop sounds like what you need

Comment: Please see my update with example code

Comment: @statox I removed my comment because I had a feeling that the indentation would not match a whole tab length. After thoughts, it seems to me that it would be the role of `autoindent` and `smartindent` or maybe the lsp for python to handle this gracefully.

Comment: Yes given the updates `expandtab` is not the way to go. I think this is something which might be controlled by [`:h 'formatoptions'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatoptions%27) (but I'm not sure I didn't checked). But using an external [`:h 'formatprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatprg%27) directly setting the option or by wrappers like [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) is probably a good solution too.

Comment: OP, you might just want to run black or similar on save (I do this via ALE for python)—works wonders for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A working, hacky solution

```
function! Visual_indent_with_space() range abort
  '<,'>g/./exe "normal! " v:count1 . "I "
endfunction
vnoremap <leader><space> :call Visual_indent_with_space()<cr>
```

Breaking down: `'<,'>g/./exe "normal! " v:count1 . "I "`

- `'<,'>`: use the selected range
- `g/./`: apply a global command to each selected line (`.` matches each line)
- `exe "normal! "` execute a normal command
- `v:count1 . "I "` insert `v:count1` spaces at the beginning of these lines

From the `:h v:count` and `:h` v:count1`:

```
v:count     The count given for the last Normal mode command.  Can be used
            to get the count before a mapping.  Read-only.
```

```
v:count1    Just like "v:count", but defaults to one when no count is
            used.
```

Also see:

- `:h :global`
- `:h :range`
- `:h :execute`

---

#### An elegant solution that does not work as expected

This would be an elegant solution, but it only works on the first line.

Type `[N]<leader><space>` to insert `[N]` spaces at the beginning of selected lines.

```
vnoremap <leader><space> @='I <C-V><Esc>'<CR>
```

- `@`: execute the content of the register
- `=`: use the `expression register`
- `''`: boundaries of the content to load in the `expression register`
- `I` : insert a space at the start of the line
- `<c-v><esc>`: input a `<escape` character (`<c-v>` escapes the character)
- `<cr>`: validate the command

---

#### Not an elegant solution

With this, you can select your lines and hit the mapping to insert a space at the beginning of the selected lines:

```
vnoremap <leader><space> :norm I<space><cr>gv
```

- `:norm`: start a normal command (i.e. like in `normal` mode) from command-line
- `I`: start inserting at the beginning of the line.
- `<space>`: insert a space
- `<cr>`: validate the command
- `gv`: go back to visual mode (so you can repeat the process)

If your leader is `space`, you can mash space to insert as many as you want.

If it is not, you could map with `<space><space>`:

```
vnoremap <space><space> :norm I<space><cr>gv
```

Comment: Don't you mean I can insert a SPACE using that mapping? What does `:norm` and `I` do?

Comment: Indeed, I'm editing the post for more clarity.

Comment: I love your solution. Would it be possible to supply a count, i.e. `[N]<leader><space>`? I don't have sufficient Vim scripting skills to accomplish that.

Comment: @Shuzheng I got it!

Comment: Thank you, awesome work! Why do you call it a hacky solution? Also, why does `v:count` work? It gets the count for the last Normal mode command, but in this case you are executing a Visual mode command? By “command-line” you mean Ex mode, right?

Comment: I call it 'hacky' because I'm think there should be a way to make the second solution work properly, I'm missing something. And because it does work thanks to the function (not without it, I have no idea why), and because `v:count1` works (I don't know why either). I meant `:h command-line` which is not `:h :Ex-mode`. Mode naming in vim can be confusing.

Comment: Alright, after having read `h: command-line`, it really is Ex mode command-line window. Also, I've added `exe "!normal" "gv"` as a second line to the function; don't know if it could be added to the first line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110911/discussion-between-biggybi-and-shuzheng).

Answer (score 1):

I just do column selection + copy for such unaligned movement of my code.

So... first I have `expandtab` (`et`) as part of my settings at the bottom of my file like so:

```
// vim: ts=4 sw=4 et
```

This means the `tabstop` is at 4 characters, the `shiftwidth` is also at 4 characters, and `expandtab` is also turned on (so no tabs anywhere, just spaces).

When I have a problem like yours above, so this code:

```
proj_object = self.session.query(Project) \
                        .filter(Project.id == parsed_proj.id) \
                        .one_or_none()
```

I go under the first line and select using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> (column select), in this case go down once, do `y` to yank that column and then `p` to copy the column. I repeat the `p` until the alignment is correct (twice in your example).

Here is a screenshot showing the selection of the column:

[image]

As long as all the characters before the `.` are spaces, the <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> can happen at any location.

***Note:** when the selection is rather large, I use my mouse. Although it's possible to enter the column selection with the mouse, it require a quadruple click which I find annoying. However, with just one left click and selection, then <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> problem solved! You can actually use <kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> any number of times to switch between the two selection modes (and <kbd>V</kbd> too [capital], which is used to select whole lines).*

Comment: I think you mean y to yank and not Y

Comment: This is indeed the way to go if you don't want any config. Besides, I think you could use a motion instead of the mouse, in the case of large selection. `<c-d>` could be a solution, or `}` if you happen to have an empty line after the block, or even better: `/^[^ ]` (find next line starting with a character that is not a space), which you could map to something!

Comment: Yes, indeed, you can use any kind of movement include a search. When I have an array, for example, which I have aligned, I can use `[]` to reach the `};` at the end. (I do mostly C++).

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to success:

1. `Ctrl` + `V` and select the lines you want to add indentation to using arrow keys,
2. `Shift` + <kbd>i</kbd> and add the number of spaces require to align the first line,
3. Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and watch the magic happen!!!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! `<C-v>` is visual block (no shift needed). Also you can use `\`` backticks for code formatting, or `<kbd>` tags if you want to highlight a key like `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>`. Feel free to [edit] :)

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I kept using shift :P